# Почему приходят не все поля из базы по запросу

Tags: php, yii2, activerecord

Есть запрос в БД

```
$platform = Questionnaire::find()->select(['q.full_name_company', 'q.real_level','u.username','up.password'])
                ->from(Questionnaire::tableName().' as q')
                ->leftJoin(User::tableName().' as u','q.id = u.company_id')
                ->leftJoin(UserPass::tableName().' as up', 'u.id = up.user_id')
                ->where(['q.id' => $id])->one();
```

в блоке `->select(['q.full_name_company', 'q.real_level','u.username','up.password'])`
указаны все поля которые нужно получить.
но в итоговом объекте только два значения `full_name_company` и `real_level` из таблицы `Questionnaire`, `u.username` и `up.password` нет в свойствах объекта.

Если добавить в запрос опцию `->asArray()` то в ответе в массиве все поля на месте.

Почему это происходит? Нужно получить именно объект, т.к далее свойства перезаписываются.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запрашиваешь ведь `Questionnaire::find()` и получаешь данные только этой модели. Остальные надо получать через реляцию, если эти данные в других моделях. Также надо не забыть о ленивой и жадной подгрузке данных и других таблиц.